# WSO2 IoT server connected cup sample agent failing to connect to MQTT broker

Tags: wso2, mqtt, wso2-iot

I have imported the WSO2 IoT server Connected Cup sample device agent into Eclipse IDE, and when it tries to connect  to MQTT broker a MQTTSecurityException is thrown which states that the user name or password in not valid. I see that user name is created from the token attribute in the request, but I don’t know how to support a right one, i.e. one that would be accepted by the OAuth2 service. There isn’t any hint in the documentation on this topic, so I would appreciate any advice.

Also, I would like to take a more deep insight into the VirtualFireAlarm sample code, so please could you tell me where to find the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT broker in wso2 IoT Server has a pluggable authentication and authorization, by default it comes with an OAuth based authentication, where it uses an empty password and uses an OAuth token for the username. You can generate a token by following the docs in https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Password+Grant.

Implementation of this extension is explained in https://medium.com/@ayyoobhamza/authentication-and-authorization-extension-for-mqtt-wso2-message-broker-2495fb2fa56e and https://medium.com/@ayyoobhamza/oauth-authentication-and-authorization-with-mqtt-for-iot-devices-a42019187a05

Implementation of the virtual firealarm can be found in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins/tree/master/components/device-types/virtual-fire-alarm-plugin